# java - StringUtils.join() returning pointer

Tags: java, types, return-value, primitive

I was trying to join the elements of an array via the `StringUtils.join(array, separator)` method from the Apache commons library. Can anyone please explain me why I cannot get the resulting string and only a pointer to its location if I use an array of primitive types like `int[]` ?
Please see example code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] s = new String[]{"Anna","has", "apples"};
    System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(s, " "));

    int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
    System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(a, " "));

    Integer[] b = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
    System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(b, " "));
}
```

Only using `Integer` arrays works. I understood that arrays of primitives are internally treated differently than ArrayList or other higher order objects, but then why is it possible (same topic more or less but a different question maybe) to instantiate a `HashMap<String, int[]>` without any warnings, exceptions? Are the arrays internally wrapped in another object? Only for maps? From what I read from the doc you cannot parametrize a map, set, array list etc with primitive types, which I understand, but then... I find it a bit confusing. Any reasonable explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the signature for `int` arrays of `StringUtils#join`:

```
join(byte[] array, char separator)
```

You called `join` using

```
StringUtils.join(a, " "),
```

using a String instead of a char.
Try using

```
StringUtils.join(a, ' ')
```

instead.

What happened is that your call matched another signature:

```
join(T... elements),
```

so your arguments get interpreted as two objects, an integer array and a String with a space character. While creating the result string, the method concatenated the string representation of the integer array with the string.

Comment: It is the same effect if I use StringUtils.join(intArray). I do not need to put any separator, it was just for example purposes. Passing an array of int (primitives) and calling any of the method's signatures (i.e., with or without separator, separator as char or string yields same effect). Try: `int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
  
  System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(a, ' '));
  System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(a));
  System.out.println(StringUtilities.join(a, " "));`

Comment: Calling `join(a)` also matches the varargs signature, so you will get the intArray's _object_ string representation, which happens to be the output explained by @Kayaman. If you want to concatenate an int array with a separator char, you'll have to use the correct char argument. Thus the correct method gets called (the one that creates strings from the single int array entries).

Comment: @Marius I'm having a hard time believing that `int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; StringUtils.join(a, ' ');` doesn't call [the correct method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28int[],%20char%29)

Comment: @Kayaman just try the above code posted as a comment for Katja's answer. BTW, sorry for the `StringUtilities` class instead of `StringUtils`. It is my own utilities class extending the `StringUtils` from apache.

Comment: @Marius I tried all of the examples. The call using `(a, ' ')` returns "1 2 3". The call using `(a, " ")` returns a string similar to "[I@659e0bfd " (note: there is a space character at the end, the result of this call being interpreted as vararg arguments of `object` type).

Comment: @Marius Which version of Apache Commons are you using, and are you sure your `StringUtilities` class doesn't have anything that would mess the calls?

Comment: Now I start to get confused. See the screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/ilkomm5ep/). Can it be the java version? I got 1.7 in my IDE. Apache commons lang 3.31. Made also explicit call to StringUtils.join(intArray, charSeparator) as you can see

Comment: That is strange. Just tried with 3.3.1 with the correct results. You imported `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`, right? Can you step into the call and see which method gets called and by what method?

Comment: Yeah, Check out this screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/exkcjg87h/). I have also cleaned the project and made two sets of tests one via the apache's `StringUtils` and one via my utility class `StringUtilities` extending apache's class :/ What jre/jdk are you using in your IDE?

Comment: I'm using 8u40. I know this sounds stupid, but the variable definition `char ch = ' ';` compiles, right? From the last output of your screenshot, it seems like your chars are interpreted as strings...

Comment: Yeah. I know what you mean. That's what I saw also, but I said to myself it cannot be.. then I cleaned the project, rebuild.. still same thing. Everything compiles, no warnings/errors regarding that piece of code. I should try to switch and put java 1.8 in the environment. Already i saw that there are differences between java 1.7 and 1.8 related to the precision/rounding somewhere. I get different results running the soft via the IDE and as a .jar file. Mainly this occurs when I calculate some percentiles... but until that issue. gotta make my own String joining method :| Thanks for your time

Comment: Got he same pb. join(int[], char) was calling join(T...) because an int array is not an Object array (primitive type).

Comment: @Arnaud I still can't reproduce that case. _join(int[], char)_ calls the correct method for me, not _join(T...)_.

Comment: @Katja I'm using Oracle jdk 1.7.0_75 64 bits. It may be jdk-dependant.

Answer (score 4):

An array of ints (a primitive) is an object.

I suspect the implementation doesn't support primitive arrays, and calls `toString()` on them, resulting in something like `[I@659e0bfd` (which translates to single dimensional (only one `[`) array of `I`nts and its "memory location").

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Saw this the first time some months ago while calling the toString() on some arrays, but I was expecting this to be solved, in terms of either implementing the toString() methods for primitive types or warn the user that this cannot be achieved. Which one's fault is it? Java or Apache? I guess Java.. apache just makes use of the API

Comment: It's Apache that's "at fault". Primitive types can't have a `toString()` method, since primitives don't have methods (and that's not the issue). Arrays don't override toString(), because that could be potentially devastating (imagine you have a `byte[10000000]` and somewhere someone calls `toString()` on it). If you need to pretty-print an array, use `Arrays.toString(fooArray);`

Comment: Hehehe.. true true, but the Java community should've also cleaned this "mess" or at least hide it, if an array of primitives is considered an object and has a toString() method. In any case, to prettify, that's what i was using anyhow `Arrays.toString()`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You should mark Katja's answer as correct, since her reasoning is the right one. Turns out it's not Java's or Apache's fault ;)

Comment: see my comment for her answer

Comment: I read a book said autoboxing was added in JAVA 1.5, that's where I got frastructed.After deep dive into the autoboxing in the specification, I found the following 

no permitted conversion from any array type to any class type other than Object or String. 

https://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/autoboxing.html